# equivalent of hierarchy in emgu

Tags: opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I am converting Python OpenCV code to Emgu.
In Python, function `findContours` can return `hierarchy`

> hierarchy – Optional output vector, containing information about the image topology. It has as many elements as the number of contours. For each i-th contour contours[i] , the elements hierarchy[i][0] , hiearchy[i][1] , hiearchy[i][2] , and hiearchy[i][3] are set to 0-based indices in contours of the next and previous contours at the same hierarchical level, the first child contour and the parent contour, respectively. If for the contour i there are no next, previous, parent, or nested contours, the corresponding elements of hierarchy[i] will be negative.

Unfortunately in Emgu I can't not return such array for `findContours` function.Is there any equivalent for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you choose `CV_RETR_TREE` as retrieval type, the `Contour<Point>` that is returned will contain a hierarchical tree structure.

This image from [here](http://jmpelletier.com/a-simple-opencv-tutorial/) shows how you can navigate in the hierarchy using `h_next` and `v_next` pointers in OpenCV (i.e. `HNext` and `VNext` in Emgu CV).

[image: Tree structure]

In this way, you can get the whole hierarchy.

Comment: The link is broken.